# How to integrate Spring Cloud Data Flow with Spring Boot Admin for batch applications monitoring?

Tags: spring-batch, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-boot-admin, spring-batch-admin

Can we integrate Spring Cloud Data Flow with Spring Boot Admin. I am new to these technologies so some additional enlightenment will be appreciated.

We have a Spring Boot Admin in place to monitor various microservices. Now we have implemented some batch applications as well. So the goal is to monitor and manage the batch applications and other applications in a single place.

Answer (score 1):

As of writing this, I see that Spring Boot Admin does not provide support for Spring Batch: https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin/issues/461.

On the other side, Spring Cloud DataFlow provides comprehensive support to monitor and operate Spring Batch (Boot based) apps, with a UI and a REST API.

You are asking "Can we integrate Spring Cloud Data Flow with Spring Boot Admin". I believe if you have SCDF in place, there is no need to integrate it with Spring Boot Admin, as it already provides what you are asking for.

Now if you really want a central place to administer all your apps (web and batch) in Spring Boot Admin, it is up to the Spring Boot Admin project to add support for Spring Batch.

Comment: I am asking about Spring Boot Admin. Not Spring Batch admin.

Comment: My bad.. I was reading too fast :-) I will update the answer accordingly.